# Android Studio build faild

Tags: android, android-studio

XXXX/build/intermediates/res/qyer/debug/drawable-hdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png: error: Duplicate file.
XXXX/build/intermediates/res/qyer/debug/drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher.png: Original is here. The version qualifier may be implied.
Error:Execution failed for task ':XXXX:processQyerDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/22.0.0/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

```
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
```

How I Get It~！ Please help Me~!

Comment: you have 2 resource with the same name.

Comment: you have the drawable, ic_launcher in both the folders drawable_hdpi_V4 and drawable_hdpi, both are same images, in their width and height, that is why it may show error, please delete once and clean and try again

Answer (score 1):

Both drawable-hdpi-v4 and drawable-hdpi folders are respresenting hdpi. You do not need two application icon for same screen size. Just delete one of ic_launcher.png in drawable-hdpi-v4 or drawable-hdpi. Then, it should be fine.

Comment: hey, @Joshua from which folder i have to delete the resource? the XXXX/build/intermediates/res/qyer/debug/drawable-hdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png is autogenerated. right?

Comment: @bachu You need to have at most 1 ic_launcher in 1 screen size. For example, hdpi and hdpi-v4 are represent the same screen size (i.e. hdpi).
Or you can have only 1 ic_launcher for all screen size.
If you want to know the name of different screen size, you can check 
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

I do not think ic_launcher will be auto-generated after you delete but it should be auto-created after you start a new project.

Comment: @Joshua i have only one hdpi in drawable and one in mipmap? what should i delete?